# Why isn't my VBA sorting my column data correctly?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to delete the first row of the Excel sheet and sort a specific column using its name "CUST_RELPO". I am using the column header name since the name may change.

Sorting and copying the column from the second row since I do need to copy the column header.

```
Sub ClearFirstRow()
'
' ClearFirstRow Macro
'

'
Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Cells.Select
  Dim rngcustrelpo As Range
  xindex = Application.ActiveCell.Column
  Set rngcustrelpo = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Find("CUST_RELPO")
  If rngcustrelpo Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "CUST_RELPO column was not found."
    Exit Sub
    End If
    'Cells.Select
    Range(rngcustrelpo, rngcustrelpo.End(xlDown)).Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("BACKORDER").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=ActiveSheet.UsedRange, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortTextAsNumbers
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("BACKORDER").Sort
        .SetRange ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Set rngcustrelpo1 = rngcustrelpo.Offset(1, 0)
    Range(rngcustrelpo1, rngcustrelpo1.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
End Sub
```

However, it is not sorting the data like I am expecting. I am not sure what I am missing here.

Comment: I am checking if CustRelPO exists and then proceed with sorting... I have problem with specifying range while sorting.

Comment: Describe your results a bit more.  Are the column headers on row 2?  If you step through (F8) does it get to the line of code that sorts?

Comment: Just guessing - can you change `ActiveSheet.UsedRange` with `Selection` and try?

Answer (score 0):

`Key:=ActiveSheet.UsedRange` is a complete misunderstanding of the sort method. (Usedrange covers the whole used area on the sheet - often "empty" cells, too.) The same applies to `.SetRange ActiveSheet.UsedRange`. It is not bad just needless. `SetRange` is needed when you want to limit the area to be sorted. If you want to sort on only one key (column), then change this

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("BACKORDER").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=ActiveSheet.UsedRange, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= xlSortTextAsNumbers
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("BACKORDER").Sort
    .SetRange ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

to this:

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("BACKORDER").Sort
    .Key rngcustrelpo
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Order:=xlAscending
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortOn:=xlSortOnValues
    .DataOption:= xlSortTextAsNumbers
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

And you can find more info here: [Excel SortFields add then sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24352229/excel-sortfields-add-then-sort) and here: [Most efficient way to sort and sort syntax VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26349980/most-efficient-way-to-sort-and-sort-syntax-vba)